# Asynchronous Sort for MongoDB in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I am using MongoDB and .Net in visual studio to make a web API.
It works but I'm trying to make this asynchronous

I am trying to get the most recent record added to a collection

```cs
public T LoadRecentRecord<T>(string collectionName)
{   
    var collection = db.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
    return collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).Sort("{_id:-1}").Limit(1).First();
}
```

Comment: Most of the collection methods have an _async_ version also. See some examples at the [MongoDb C# Driver Examples - Read Operations](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.12/reference/driver/crud/reading/).

Comment: See Sorting documents section of [Quick Tour Tutorials](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.12/getting_started/quick_tour/) - for performing an async read with sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the methods which read or write data to the database have an `async` version. In your case, it is the method `FirstAsync()`. Your code should look something like that:

```cs
public async Task<T> LoadRecentRecord<T>(string collectionName)
{   
    var collection = db.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
    var item = await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).Sort("{_id:-1}").Limit(1).FirstAsync();
    return item;
}
```